# Workaround for Generic Mixins in Typescript

Tags: typescript, generics, mixins

I am relatively new to Typescript. It seems that mixins with generics are a problem there, and promptly I ran into it. Consider the following example:

(**Edit**: integrated Titian's answer into approach 2 and added `setValue()` to better illustrate new problem.)

```
class A<T> {
  public constructor(public a: T) {}
  public setValue(a: T): void {this.a = a;}
}
class B<T> extends A<T> {public constructor(public a: T, public b: T) {super(a);}}

// approach 1
function mixinC(Base: ???) { // ??? = typeof A vs. ??? = typeof B vs. ??? = any
  return class CMixin<T> extends Base<T> {}; //...
}
// approach 2
type Constructor<T> = new (...args: any[]) => T;
function mixinC<T extends Constructor<A<unknown>>>(Base: T) {
  return class CMixin extends Base {}; //...
}

// test 1
class C<T> extends mixinC(A)<T> {}
interface C<T> extends A<T> {}
const c = new C<string>('123');
c.setValue(7); // no error, although 7 is not string
console.log(c.a);

// test 2
class D<T> extends mixinC(B)<T> {}
interface D<T> extends B<T> {}
const d = new D<string>('465', '789');
console.log(d.a, d.b);
```

I want that both tests work, but neither of the approaches works.

The first approach would work (I think) if there was a way to dynamically tell the compiler wether `Base` will be `typeof A` or `typeof B`, but `mixinC<T>(Base: typeof T)` does not work because T is a type and not a value. I also tried `any` as type; this seems to work on the surface, but I then can access arbitrary, undefined properties on each instance of `C` (such as `c.xyz`).

The second approach is in principal very similar to [ES6 Mixin with generic type in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43086637/es6-mixin-with-generic-type-in-typescript), but the main difference is that `A` (comparable to `BaseClass` there) here is a generic type. So what should I replace the ??? with? Maybe it would work if I could do `??? = A<T2>` with a parameter type `T2`, but where should I define this parameter?

@**edit**: `c.setValue(7);` probably does not raise an error because there now actually co-exist two versions of `setValue`: a `string` one (the correct one) and an `unknown` one, with the latter allowing `7`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why `Constructor<any>` lets you access any property, I would actually classify this as a Typescript bug. Using `{}` instead seems to prevent this undesired behavior, and also keeps the forwarding of generic parameters from the target class to the resulting mixed class:

```
class A<T> {public constructor(public a: T) {}}
class B<T> extends A<T> {public constructor(public a: T, public b: T) {super(a);}}

type Constructor<T> = new (...args: any[]) => T;
function mixinC<T extends Constructor<A<unknown>>>(Base: T) {
  return class CMixin extends Base {
      test() {
          this.a
      }
  }; //...
}

// test 1
class C<T> extends mixinC(A)<T> {}
const c = new C<string>('123');
console.log(c.a);
c.xyzqqq // error


// test 2
class D<T> extends mixinC(B)<T> {}
const d = new D<string>('465', '789');
console.log(d.a, d.b);
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECCA8AVAfNA3gBwK4CMQEthpgB7AOwgBcAnLYSk6gCmz0OjAC5pEBKdAL4CAUKEgwAQklQBTAB6UZZACYwEKdKwJFSFGnQbMt7LjwA00Y0Rzc+6CFgwzmYXgG4hw4ZQCeT6ADC5FS09IzS0AC80GQyAO7QTAB0KWDUAOYQ3GBkPgDaALr8kaiIbsIAZlhk9Pjk0AC2+HL4ZAFI0PKKKjBBeqGG8AjVANZkJHFkyNNMEpAytvxowtDQ1DKUWNRkxOBQgQCyza2dCkqq0HMQMugrq-eKVExLd-dv0JQAFvgQSWCv9xEqwEbmgAHowSkksIRMIIR8ZFRoABGUR7XoRLrnGBNFptJiwXgRNAiXRIojRWIJdohVrpZBMADkyIATABmRnuUTBEggGRJEAkdJMYB-LmiuQ+ABeAEc5eCwZ1qNRGF44YrHpRoCy0eJoAARTFnHqNY74iREjQk7l6aDKKIxeIG+C0sj0pkAFgAbABWRkWRkAdgAHABOTnlMm8-mC4XKP4WeM4LlAA)

Comment: Interesting, thanks. But the problem here is that `Base` then has nothing to do with `A` (or `B`). So, if `CMixin` contains eg. a method `test() {console.log(this.a);}`, this would not work because `a` does not exist.

Comment: @Remirror `A<unknown>` (or `A<any>`) should work instead of `{}` if you want to access specific members of `A` (edited answer)

Comment: I also tried that, but except for the toy example, this should not work. I have edited my question correspondingly to illustrate the problem (see `setValue` method).